# using Hibernate FetchType.Eager in Resfull api in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on spring + Hibernate project.and  there exist one to many relation between two entity  **Category and Product**  and i make restfull webservices for **product** entity which is child of **category** and by using **fetch.Eager** it give one record repeatedly with parent record  but i want to get only **product** record i don'nt know how to achieve that.

my Entity classes  are 
**product class**

```
@Entity
public class product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String brand;
    private String description;
    private Double unitPrice;
    private Integer quantity;
    private Integer purchases;
    @Column(name="is_active")
    private boolean active;
    private Integer view;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")

    private category category1;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="supplier_id")
    private User user1;
    public product() {

        this.code="PRD"+UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(25).toUpperCase();

    }
}
```

**Category class**

```
@Entity
public class category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    @Column(name="image_url")
    private String imageUrl;
    private boolean active=true;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="category1")
    private List<product> products;
}
```

and the result is

[{"id":1,"code":"PRDABC123DEFX","name":"iphone.5s","brand":"Apple","description":"this is the best quality mobile","unitPrice":10.0,"quantity":2,"purchases":0,"active":true,"view":2,"category1":{"id":2,"name":"Mobile","description":"this is description for Mobile","imageUrl":"CAT_1.png","active":true,"products":[{"id":1,"code":"PRDABC123DEFX","name":"iphone.5s","brand":"Apple","description":"this is the best quality mobile","unitPrice":10.0,"quantity":2,"purchases":0,"active":true,"view":2,"category1":{"id":2,"name":"Mobile","description":"this is description for Mobile","imageUrl":"CAT_1.png","active":true,"products":[{"id":1,"code":"PRDABC123DEFX","name":"iphone.5s","brand":"Apple","description":"this is the best quality mobile","unitPrice":10.0,"quantity":2,"purchases":0,"active":true,"view":2,"category1":{"id":2,"name":"Mobile","description":"this is description for Mobile","imageUrl":"CAT_1.png","active":true,"products":[{"id":1,"code":"PRDABC123DEFX","name":"iphone.5s","brand":"Apple","description":"this is the best quality mobile","unitPrice":10.0,"quantity":2,"purchases":0,"active":true,"view":2,"category1":{"id":2,"name":"Mobile","description":"this is description for Mobile","imageUrl":"CAT_1.png","active":true,"products":[{"id":1,"code":"PRDABC123DEFX","name":"iphone.5s","brand":"Apple","description":"this is the best quality mobile","unitPrice":10.0,"quantity":2,"purchases":0,"active":true,"view":2,"category1":{"id":2,"name":"Mobile","description":"this is description for Mobile","imageUrl":"CAT_1.png","active":true,"products":[{"id":1,"code":"PRDABC123DEFX","name":"iphone.5s","brand":"Apple","description":"this is the best quality mobile","unitPrice":10.0,"quantity":2,"purchases":0,"active":true,"view":2,"category1":{"id":2,"name":"Mobile","description":"this is description for Mobile","imageUrl":"CAT_1.png","active":true,"products":[{"id":1,"code":"PRDABC123DEFX","name":"iphone.5s","brand":"Apple","description":"this is the best quality mobile","unitPrice":10.0,"quantity":2,"purchases":0,"active":true,"view":2,"category1":{"id":2,"name":"Mobile","description":"this is description for Mobile","imageUrl":"CAT_1.png","active":true,"products":[{"id":1,"code":"PRDABC123DEFX","name":"iphone.5s","brand":"Apple","description":"this is the best quality mobile","unitPrice":10.0,"quantity":2,"purchases":0,"active":true,"view":2,"category1":{"id":2,"name":"Mobile","description":"this is description for Mobile","imageUrl":"CAT_1.png","active":true,"products":[{"id":1,"code":"PRDABC123DEFX","name":"iphone.5s","brand":"Apple","description":"this is the best quality mobile","unitPrice":10.0,"quantity":2,"purchases":0,"active":true,"view":2,"category1":{"id":2,"name":"Mobile","description":"this is description for Mobile","imageUrl":"CAT_1.png","active":true,"products":[{"id":1,"code":"PRDABC123DEFX","name":"iphone.5s","brand":"Apple","description":"this is the best quality mobile","unitPrice":10.0,"quantity":2,"purchases":0,"active":true,"view":2,"category1":{"id":2,"name":"Mobile","description":"this is description for Mobile","imageUrl":"CAT_1.png","active":true,"products":[{"id":1,"code":"PRDABC123DEFX","name":"iphone.5s","brand":"Apple","description":"this is the best quality mobile","unitPrice":10.0,"quantity":2,"purchases":0,"active":true,"view":2,"category1":{"id":2,"name":"Mobile","description"}

this is description for

but i want only **product** table record

The JsonController class is

```
@Controller

public class JsonController {
    @Autowired
     private  productDao productDao;
     @RequestMapping(value="/json")
     @ResponseBody
     public List<product> getAllProducts(){


         return productDao.getAllProduct();
     }



}
```

Comment: You failed to post the definition of the productDao class, which is the one that gives you the wrong results. Please note than in Java the convention is to have the name of classes begin with uppercase letters. So, your classes should be named Product, Category, and ProductDao.

Answer (score 0):

You should ignore `category1` field for serialization by using [JsonIgnoreProperties](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) annotation in your `Product` class:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"category1"})
public class product { 

   //...

}
```

**Note:**
 Class name should (by [convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411) ) begin with upper case.